# Trigger event programmatically and pass value to second page?

Tags: c#, uwp, routed-events

I want to pass a value from Mainpage to Page2. When I click `Button_Click` the variable “t” is passed to Page2.

However I need to trigger the `Button_Click` event from code, but then a “NullReferenceException” is thrown.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Button_Click(new object(), new RoutedEventArgs());
    }

    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string t = "Test";
        navigate_page2(t);
    }

    public void navigate_page2(string t)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), t);
    }
}
```

`Button_Click(new object(), new RoutedEventArgs());` triggers the `Button_Click` event to do stuff, except when "navigate_page2" is called.

What is the difference between directly clicking and triggering the Button from code? I guess it is the "new RoutedEventArgs" somehow, but I don't know how to handle that... Thank you for any response!

Comment: Replace `Button_Click(new object(), new RoutedEventArgs());` with `Button_Click(sender, e);` that will trigger the events without getting a `NullReferenceException`  -If you experience more difficulties, please share more info :)

Comment: refer this code https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/de41d6/navigation-techniques-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Isn't my first comment easier though...? The link you gave seems to be using all this complicated code, even though it could be much, much easier :) I liked the article though!

Comment: Also, remove unnecessary code `this.InitializeComponent();`, and do `InitializeComponent();` - It takes space, and it unneeded :)

Comment: @Momoro. When I simply replace as you say, sender and e  "do not exist in the current context". Seems it does not match with the arguments of the Button_Click - event...

Comment: The problem is you are still using `RoutedEventArgs` - You should just do `EventArgs e` so it will work right. If you experience more problems, tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not call `Button_Click` directly, this method is associated with events in XAML.

If you want to re-use the code in the `Button_Click` event, you can pack it as a method to call.

**Update**

> but then a “NullReferenceException” is thrown.

The problem is in `this.Frame`. for your current page, `this.Frame` does not exist. You need to create a sub-frame in xaml.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame"/>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        btn_handle();
    }

    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn_handle();
    }

    public void btn_handle()
    {
        string t = "Test";
        navigate_page2(t);
    }

    public void navigate_page2(string t)
    {
        MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), t);
    }
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Zhang. Unfortunately I get the NullReferenceException as well. Do I need a special using directive? And, this is UWP - tagged it, but did not mention it explicitely...

Comment: Hi, I fixed my answer, please check.

Comment: Zhang. That works! Although I do not understand yet why this is so. I thought that my MainPage.xaml is from where I go to Page2.xaml. And even more I do not understand why a click on the Button does not need this additional MainFrame… Nevertheless, your solution solves my problem and eventually I will understand while progressing in C#. Many thanks for your help, Richard Zhang!

Comment: In UWP, `Page` always needs `Frame` to render, just like you always open a web page in a browser window. If you want to navigate to `Page2`, you need a `Frame` to render it, but unfortunately, `this.Frame` does not exist under the current conditions, you can use `var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame; ` to get the `RootFrame` of the current window, it is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you are trying to pass a value from one page to another let take example for two forms that you need to pass one value from a form to another with a trigger of any click of button.

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler TextEvent;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        if (TextEvent != null)
        {
            TextEvent(label1.Text, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 obj = new Form2();
        obj.Show();
        obj.TextEvent += obj_TextEvent;
    }

    void obj_TextEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = sender.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here what I am doing is I have made an event in Form2 which triggers at clicking Button1 of Form2 and the data is pass as a sender to Form1 where Form2 obj has initiated the event and set label1 of Form1 as label1.Text = sender.ToString();

Comment: The question is about UWP, not the WinForms

Comment: OK not an issue with that if you will creat a event for a trigger it works the same, basically its an example to understand or say reference.